# Convert comma separated data from columns to separate rows by Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a situation where I need to take data from few columns of a html table and display the data in separate rows.

```css
.new td {border: 1px solid; padding: 2px;}
```

```html
<div class="new"><table>
<tr>
<td>Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4</td><td>Age1,Age2,Age3,Age4</td><td>M,M,F,M</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name5,Name6,Name7</td><td>Age5,Age6,Age7</td><td>F,F,F</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

Now I want to separately change the data from each row to display separately in rows like below on the html page. Here the comma separated values can change in each row with new form submissions.

```css
table td {border: 1px solid; padding: 2px;}
```

```html
<p>For Row1</p>
<table>
<tr><td>Name1</td><td>Age1</td><td>M</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name2</td><td>Age2</td><td>M</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name3</td><td>Age3</td><td>F</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name4</td><td>Age4</td><td>M</td></tr>
</table>

<p>For Row2</p>
<table>
<tr><td>Name5</td><td>Age5</td><td>F</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name6</td><td>Age6</td><td>F</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name7</td><td>Age7</td><td>F</td></tr>
</table>
```

Can this be done with Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For your information, yes it's possibile, but first try it yourself, there are plenty of guides about js online...

Comment: to further your start; parse the items you want into an object of some type, likely object of arrays, each corresponding to a row.  then, loop through them and build your new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  function my_table_to_obj_arr(){
    var out=[];
    $('div.new table tr').each(function(){
      var names=$(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
        var names_arr=names.split(',');
      var ages=$(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
        var ages_arr=ages.split(',');
      var genders=$(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
        var genders_arr=genders.split(',');
      for(var key in names_arr){
       out.push({'name':names_arr[key], 'age': ages_arr[key], 'gender': genders_arr[key]});
      }
    });
    return out;
  }


  function obj_arr_to_table(_obj){
    var table=$('<table/>');
    for(var key in _obj){
       var tr=$('<tr/>');
       var td_name=$('<td/>').text(_obj[key].name);
         tr.append(td_name);
       var td_age=$('<td/>').text(_obj[key].age);
         tr.append(td_age);
       var td_gender=$('<td/>').text(_obj[key].gender);
         tr.append(td_gender);
     table.append(tr)
    }
    $('div.new').empty().append(table);
  }



  var my_obj=my_table_to_obj_arr();

  console.log(my_obj);

  obj_arr_to_table(my_obj);
```

```css
       .new td {border: 1px solid; padding: 2px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="new">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4</td><td>Age1,Age2,Age3,Age4</td><td>M,M,F,M</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name5,Name6,Name7</td><td>Age5,Age6,Age7</td><td>F,F,F</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```